# Vue Cli's default has console errors?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm trying to create a project using Vue Cli using the following lines,

```
$ npm install -g vue-cli
$ vue init webpack my-project
$ cd my-project
$ npm install
$ npm run dev
```

And in the console of the build, it has the following error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
at Object.extractShopifyDomain (content.min.js:14)
    at Object.extractCurrentDomain (content.min.js:14)
    at new <anonymous> (content.min.js:16)
    at content.min.js:15
```

Is it an issue with the current Vue Cli or am I doing something wrong? I haven't touched any scripts or edited anything yet. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same thing. Discovered it was the Coupons at Checkout chrome extension causing the error.

Comment: same here,  wasted 15 mins looking for that in my React code

Answer (score 1):

Try to update nodejs & npm. Remove node_modules folder and run `npm install` again. Maybe it will help.